# State vector after applying CNOT

Tags: quantum-gate

[image]

In the circuit, the CNOT gate is applied in 11 state and it should transform into 10 state. But why is the probability of getting 01 state 100 percent?

Comment: Actually, the second digit of the bat plot refers to `q0`, the result is correct, it's just a little weird.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right, that $CNOT |11\rangle = |10\rangle $ in the usual setting. But the reason why you see the answer as $|01\rangle$ instead is because Qiskit uses **little endian** convention.

See [this documentation](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.circuit.library.CXGate.html) to clear thing up.